# Can't build ParagraphVectors in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, deep-learning, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I'm using the Doc2Vec algorithm with Deeplearning4j and it works fine when I run it on my Windows 10 PC, however when I try to run it on a Linux box, i get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j
at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.inmemory.InMemoryLookupTable$Builder.<init>(InMemoryLookupTable.java:581) ~[run.jar:?]
at org.deeplearning4j.models.sequencevectors.SequenceVectors$Builder.presetTables(SequenceVectors.java:801) ~[run.jar:?]
at org.deeplearning4j.models.paragraphvectors.ParagraphVectors$Builder.build(ParagraphVectors.java:663) ~[run.jar:?]
```

I've tried this on a couple of Linux machines, both of which were running Xubuntu and had sudo permissions

Here is the code for creating my ParagraphVectors:
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

```
  LabelAwareSentenceIterator iter;
  iter = new LabelAwareListSentenceIterator(is, DELIM);
  iter.setPreProcessor(new SentencePreProcessor() {
    @Override
    public String preProcess(String sentence) {
      return new InputHomogenization(sentence).transform();
    }
  });

  TokenizerFactory tokenizerFactory = new DefaultTokenizerFactory();
  vec = new ParagraphVectors.Builder().minWordFrequency(minWordFrequency).batchSize(batchSize)
      .iterations(iterations).layerSize(layerSize).stopWords(stopWords).windowSize(windowSize)
      .learningRate(learningRate).tokenizerFactory(tokenizerFactory).iterate(iter).build();
  vec.fit();
```

And here is my pom.xml (versions are all 0.7.1, but I had been using 0.4-rc3.9 and got the same error) :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-ui-model</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-nlp</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
        <version>${nd4j.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.datavec/datavec-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
        <artifactId>datavec-api</artifactId>
        <version>${nd4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always stick to the latest version first of all. Could you post the full stack trace? This is definitely *not* the root cause. Maybe try using nd4j-native-platform instead? Usually this is a problem with missing native artifacts.

Comment: Thanks, I used nd4j-native-platform and now it is running on Linux.  Strangely, I'm using it as part of an Apache Storm cluster and I'm still getting the same error, but it works with native-platform when on a LocalCluster, so it's a Storm issue now.